# Partial derivative of endogenous variables and total differentiation

Tags: systems-of-equations, partial-derivative, implicit-differentiation

I am given two equations:

$x=\frac{u}{v}(1- \frac{1-y+py}{p})$
and
$y\frac{x}{2}= a\frac{p}{1-y+py}$

where $p$, $a$, $u$ and $v$ are parameters. I am asked to provide $\frac{\delta x}{\delta y}$ and $\frac{\delta y}{\delta x}$

I derived the corresponding partial derivatives to find:

$\frac{\delta x}{\delta y}=\frac{u}{v}\frac{1-p}{p}$
and
$\frac{\delta y}{\delta x}=\frac{-2a}{x^2}\frac{1}{2p-1}$ (using implicit differentiation for $\frac{\delta y}{\delta x}$)

My question is whether this approach is correct or I need to apply total differentiation. If I need to apply total differentiation, I have only seen that one finds the compartive statics with respect to the parameters by finding, for example, dx/da and then setting du,dv,dp=0 via Cramers rule. Nevertheless, how would one find dx/dy?

Any help is mega appreciated.